# New variable in a panda dataframe which counts consecutive values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a panda dataframe (which is imported from excel), is made up of 2 variables, 
f is just a number
the other is a boolean for if the number is out the range

I want to create a new variable which counts consecutive TRUE vales.

I read a little online and I think the new variable could use consecutive counts but I am not sure how to implement it into this dataframe

The final dataframe should look something like this

```
f   outrange  count
1    F       0
2    F       0 
3    T       1
4    T       2
1    F       0
3    T       1
2    F       0
3    T       1  
4    T       2
```

I am very new to python so sorry if the question isn't worded correctly

Comment: Also share your Initial data.

Comment: How big is your data? I have done similar things on very large arrays using numba and for..loop; numba is very fast and plays nicely with numpy arrays (not directly with pandas dataframes)

Comment: There are 31536000 values in my data frame, I simplified it for the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used my own data as the input. Column 'A' corresponds to your 'outrange' column and 'B' corresponds to 'count' column. Please test with your actual data.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data{'A':['F','T','T','T','F','F','F','T','F','F','F','T','T','F','F','F']})
counter = 0

def conditional_cumulative_sum(x):
    global counter

    if x == 'F':
        counter = 0
        return counter
    elif x == 'T':
        counter += 1
        return counter
df['B'] = df['A'].apply(conditional_cumulative_sum)
```

Comment: This is the kind of function that lends itself perfectly to being optimised with numba. OP, just remember to use numpy arrays and not dataframes. You can easily make a dataframe after the calculations are completed.

Comment: @TurtleRocket - Performance is not important? Check my answer with timings, loops here are slow in large DataFrame.

Comment: @jezrael This ran very quickly for me

Comment: Hi TurtleRocket the solution that @jezrael gave is much faster. You are not feeling it might be because the dataset you are using is very small. There could performance issues if you are dealing with bigger datasets.

Comment: @Pythonistaanonymous Thank you for the suggestion. Point noted

Answer (score 4):

Use vectorized solution with replace `T` values:

```
a = df['outrange'] == 'T'
#if values are boolean True
#a = df['outrange']
b = a.cumsum()
df['count_new'] = b-b.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df)
   f outrange  count  count_new
0  1        F      0          0
1  2        F      0          0
2  3        T      1          1
3  4        T      2          2
4  1        F      0          0
5  3        T      1          1
6  2        F      0          0
7  3        T      1          1
8  4        T      2          2
```

**Performance**:

```
#90k
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000, ignore_index=True)

In [183]: %%timeit
     ...: a = df['outrange'] == 'T'
     ...: b = a.cumsum()
     ...: df['count_new'] = b-b.where(~a).ffill().fillna(0).astype(int)
     ...: 
7.83 ms ± 28.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [184]: %%timeit
     ...: df['B'] = df['outrange'].apply(conditional_cumulative_sum)
     ...: 
35.9 ms ± 295 µs p
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps easier with a dictionary.

```
arr = np.array([0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1]) #your array of booleans

dct = {k:0 if arr[k]<1 else 1 for k in range(len(arr))}

c = 0
for i in arr:
  if i > 0 and dct[c-1]>0:
     dct[c] = 1 + dct[c-1]
  c = c+1

pd.DataFrame([arr,dct.values()],index=["outofrange","count"]).T

#outofrange count
0           0
0           0
1           1 
1           2
0           0
1           1 
0           0
1           1
1           2
```